# JQuery error with node, jade & express

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, pug

Im geting an error saying the the $ in my js scripts are not defined, i would really love some insight into what i may be doing wrong.As a result i cant do any jquery stuff. Ive checked the resources and they all do in fact load.

Error message:
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Master Page:

```
//doctype html
html
    head
        title=title
        link(href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.0/css/materialize.min.css', rel='stylesheet')
        link(href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300|Lato:100,300' rel='stylesheet')
        link(href='/css/bootstrap.min.css' rel='stylesheet')
        link(href='/css/custom.css' rel='stylesheet')
        link(href='/css/animate.css' rel='stylesheet')
        link(href="/css/pnotify.custom.min.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css")
        link(href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet")
    body
        block content
    link(src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js' type='text/javascript')
    link(src="/js/pnotify.custom.min.js")
    link(src="/js/custom.js")
    link(src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.0/js/materialize.min.js' type='text/javascript')
```

Child Page with the javascript

```
extends layout

block content
    nav.blue.darken-4(role="navigation" style="margin-bottom: 50px")
        .nav-wrapper(style="margin-left:10px")
            a.brand-logo(href='/home') Owen's Math Game - Admin Dashboard      
            ul.right.hide-on-med-and-down
                li(class="tooltipped active" data-position="bottom" data-delay="50" data-tooltip="Profile")
                    a(href='/home')
                        i.material-icons perm_identity   
                li(class="tooltipped" data-position="bottom" data-delay="50" data-tooltip="Users")
                    a(href='/users')
                        i.material-icons search      
                li(class="tooltipped" data-position="bottom" data-delay="50" data-tooltip="Leaderboard")
                    a(href='/admin/leaderboard')
                        i.material-icons list         
                li(class="tooltipped" data-position="bottom" data-delay="50" data-tooltip="Settings")
                    a(href='/settings')
                        i.material-icons settings
                li(class="tooltipped" data-position="bottom" data-delay="50" data-tooltip="Log Out")
                    a(href='/signout')
                        i.material-icons fast_rewind
    div.container
        div.row
            div.col-sm-6.col-md-4.col-md-offset-4
                #user
                    div.signup-wall
                        a(class="tooltipped" href="#" data-position="bottom" data-delay="50" data-tooltip="I am tooltip")
                            img(class='profile-img', style="display:inline" src='/avatar-img.png')
                        h1.text-center.login-title Welcome #{user.firstName} #{user.lastName} <br/> Check your details below:
                        ul.user-details
                            li Username  #{user.username}
                            li Email    #{user.email}
                            li First Name  #{user.firstName} 
                            li Last Name #{user.lastName}

    script.
        $(document).ready(function(){
            //Initialize collapse button
            $(".button-collapse").sideNav();

            $('.tooltipped').tooltip({delay: 50});
        })
```

Adding jquery in the head doesnt change the error

Comment: instead of $(document) have you tried with jQuery(document) ? look if your js files are downloaded with firebug ;)

Comment: that gave the same error, and ye my files are loaded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declare your body content *before* loading jQuery (which is the library that defines `$`). You also use `link` instead of `script` for all your JS files.

You should move (at least) the jquery load to *before* `block content` (in the layout/"master" file). As @Radu also suggests in the comments, in the `<head>` would be a good location.

Comment: i put it as the first thing, still the same error, and no jquery animation is happening

Comment: the jquery libs should be loaded in head as robert said

Comment: @user56683 see edit, you're using `link` instead of `script`, too.

Comment: i realized that and changed it but it still doesnt work